# Why are positioned divs overlapping?

Tags: css

I have a main wrapper div with 2 content divs inside. The `position` attribute of both content divs is set to `relative`, but for some reason they're overlapping as shown here:

[image: divs]

I want the div outlined in red to be underneath the blue one and am having trouble figuring out how to do so.

```css
#wrap {
  height: 500px;
  width: 350px;
  border: 3px solid black;
}
#upper {
  position: relative;
  width: 40%;
  height: 70%;
  top: 5%;
  left: 2%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  text-align: center;
}
#lower {
  position: relative;
  width: 40%;
  height: 20%;
  left: 2%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="upper"></div>
  <div id="lower"></div>
</div>
```

Can someone please help me figure out how to align them correctly?

Comment: Add a jsfiddle with the specified issue...

Comment: add friend is written in which div ??

Comment: lower! sorry I'm making a fiddle.

Comment: I made a fiddle, thanks for the patience. https://jsfiddle.net/kfupd6hb/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The styling of the div#upperDiv has top:5% which causing this to happen. Although relative but div#upperDiv is taking the 5% top to overlap on div#lowerDiv.
Solution: EITHER take that top:5% styling off from upperDiv OR add the same top style to lowerDiv.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that `top` could have such implications, I thought it was simpler than that. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

For lower div can you try adding `clear:both;`

```
#lowerDiv {
    position: relative;
    clear:both;
    width: 40%;
    left: 2%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is happening because u r using height in percentage. As you've taken Height of upperDiv is 70%. it is taking 70% of ur main div. and ur lower div is having more data than it can adjust in the same outer div. so ur main div should big enough so that ur lowerDiv can adjust in remaining 30% of space u r providing to it. or u can adjust ur upperDiv's percentage value of height so that both can adjust in that space.

Comment: Interesting, I'll try make it more dynamic. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Let me know if you can help me figure out how to make it more dynamic. I made a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kfupd6hb/